# asking user for how many numbers they want to add then, using while-loop have the user type in those numbers and find the average

Tags: c#, .net, console

I'm struggling to get the loop to repeat according to the user's input.

```
//ask users for how many numbers they'd like to add
System.Console.Write("How many numbers would you like to 
add?: ");
int count= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int userinput= 0; 
int counter=1;


while ( counter >  count ;
{
  System.Console.Write(" please enter you number" +  
  counter + ": ");
  userinput= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

  counter ++;
}
```

this is what i have so far but i know im nowhere close to right. im a beginner in grade 11 so please be beginner friendly ! thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO, what you need to do is to collect the given numbers inside a Collection like a list or an Array and then you can calculate the Average, right now you overwrite the given number with each new input.

Comment: Ty! would you be able to show me what you're talking about?

Comment: @Mostlygoldie You need to initialize some kind of enumerable data type, e.g. an array or List, e.g.: `List<int> userList = new();` Then after the user enters a number, you add it to the list, e.g. `userList.Add(userinput);` Or you could do it without arrays or lists at all and simply have an `int` that tracks the sum, e.g. `int total = 0` and then after user inputs a number, you do `total += userinput;`. Then outside the `while` loop, you have enough info to output the average.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome! You just need to fix the condition you wrote in the while statement, the correct condition in this situation would be
`(counter <=  count)`
also you have to be careful with syntax in this line
`while ( counter <=  count ;` which is going to be `while(counter <=  count)` then finally the loop should work as expected. Hope I could help, I'm also new to this platform!